# Why are kW and kWh used the way they are?

Tags: energy, electricity, units, power

The rate of consumption of some given appliance is 1 kW. This number represents the amount of electricity this appliance consumes in an hour.

If I plug in this appliance for an hour, the consumed electricity is 1 kWh.

Why are these two units used this way? Intuitively, it feels like they should be used the other way around: kWh to measure the rate of consumption (thus the "hour" in the name), and kW to measure the electricity consumed (thus the lack of time unit in the name). Why is it not so?

If I have a car, I don't say that it can go at a speed of 60 Miles. After having driven it for an hour, I also don't step out and say that the car covered a distance of 60 mph.

Comment: *If I have a car, I don't say that it can go at a speed of 60 Miles. After having driven it for an hour, I also don't step out and say that the car covered a distance of 60 Mph.* According to your intuition, that is exactly what you are claiming because 1 Watt = 1 Joule/second. 1 kWh = 1 kilowatt-hour, not 1kilowatt per hour. kW, not KW. mph, not Mph.

Answer (score 1):

"This number represents the amount of electricity this appliance consumes in an hour." You are incorrect in your interpretation of the units. The power value tells how fast the energy is used, and can be used for any time. It is using energy at a *rate*, and you multiply that rate (the power value) by the time to get the actual energy (electricity) used. If it's on for 1 minute, the energy is 1 kilowatt-minute or 60,000 J.

A kilowatt (kW) is the rate of energy consumption, or the power. A 1 kW device uses energy (in your case, electrical) energy at a rate of 1000 joules per second (J/s). So, in 1 hour it uses 3,600,000 J = 1 kWh. kW tells you *only* the power and not how much electricity you use. kWh tells you the energy you have actually used.

Comment: But how did the unit for "energy consumed", the kWh, end up with a time unit in its name, and not the unit for power? Why didn't they just stick with the convention of the units they are derived from (the Joule and Joule/second respectively)? Wouldn't that be simpler? Or is it due to some historical oddity we are now stuck with in the present?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Not that odd. We have Newtons instead of kg-meters per second squared. If you think about it, most units have their own name and it's distance and velocity measurements that are odd in that stick with the base units, but those are also the ones that get swapped around the most based on distance and time scales being worked with.

Comment: Yes, historical, but I don't know the history. Similar to the idea of the word "pound" being used in engineering for both mass and weight.  But is the use of product units wrong? No, we say light-year (ly) for distance and electron volt (eV) for energy.

Comment: @DKNguyen Consolidating units, like with Newtons, is fine with me. I just feel that a consolidated unit that measures a rate, should be the one with the rate's denominator units in its name. I understand the technicals behind kWh and kW, but the swap makes it incredibly confusing to me. This is now opinion territory though. I was just curious about the reasons behind doing it this way and now "my" way.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Consider that ampheres is coloumbs per second, and battery capacity is measured in Amp-hours, but capacitor charge is measured in coloumbs. I would prefer joules instead of kWh, but I know that I would hate working in coloumbs/second for current instead of Amps, and coloumbs for batteries because now I have to jump back and forth between coloumbs and amps all the time.